# Keep records with a specific prefix and filter all-numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a [pyspark dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykxzW.png) looks like below:

```
serial_number
000001234
000002887
00008765
0745-218
01-7865
040/7868L
0000124
00002364
01231325246
068775H
```

I want to extract only the records that start with the prefix 0 (single 0 at start) and that are **not only** numeric. i.e. it should have alphabetic and/or special characters only numeric. So I want to [only keep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB0nx.png):

```
serial_number
0745-218
01-7865
040/7868L
068775H
```

I tried to use some regex expressions like `^0[^0]` but it also accepts all-numeric entries.

Comment: It sounds like you just need `r"0[^0]"`...

Comment: Hi Tomerikoo, i don't want the records which has only numeric and starts like morethan a zero

Comment: Yes, so as I said, `r"0[^0]"` should work for what you need...

Comment: No, it didn't work.. it is giving all results..

Comment: Add `^`: `r"^0[^0]"`

Comment: Getting 75% result using above regex, but not getting values having '/' in it. and getting only numeric values ex.020800007444441960(it should have Alpha-Numeric and specials)

Comment: Need a [mre]. This regex works exactly like you defined it https://regex101.com/r/lYdO1S/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251334/discussion-between-krishna-and-tomerikoo).

Answer (score 0):

Use rlike. Code below

```
df.where(col('serial_number').rlike('\D')&col('serial_number').rlike('^0')).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

following Hà Nguyễn's answer:

```
import re

COMPILED = re.compile("0[^0]\d*[^\d]+\d*")

serial_numbers = [
    "000001234",
    "000002887",
    "00008765",
    "0745-218",
    "01-7865",
    "040/7868L",
    "0000124",
    "00002364",
    "01231325246",
    "068775H"
] 

matching_numbers = [number for number in serial_numbers if COMPILED.match(number)]

print(matching_numbers)
```

no need of `^` as `match` matches from the start of the string.

`\d` is practically syntactic sugar for `0-9`

Comment: `"0000L"` contains non numeric `L`, the question asked for one zero at the start.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

serial_numbers = [
    "000001234",
    "000002887",
    "00008765",
    "0745-218",
    "01-7865",
    "040/7868L",
    "0000124",
    "00002364",
    "01231325246",
    "068775H"
]

pattern = "^0[^0-9]+"

matching_numbers = [number for number in serial_numbers if re.match(pattern, number)]

print(matching_numbers)
```

Comment: This just prints an empty list...

Comment: In this case, ^0[^0-9]+, this pattern only matches strings that start with 0, followed by one or more non-numeric characters.

Comment: ...which is not what is asked for here...

Comment: the answer doesn't do what the question asked